# Can not import X model

Tags: django, django-models

I'm getting this error:

> cannot import name Provider

this is my model(products/models.py):

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals

from django.db import models
from provider.models import Provider

class Product(models.Model):

    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    image = models.FileField(upload_to='products/', null=True)
    detail = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    provider = models.ForeignKey(Provider, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
   ...
   ...
```

this is my model from provider app:

```
from products.models import Product
    class Provider(models.Model):

        name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
        rut=models.CharField(max_length=13, default='9999999999')
        addres = models.CharField(max_length=100)
        contact_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    class Catalogue(models.Model):
      product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
      provider = models.ForeignKey(Provider, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
      spetial_price = models.Decimalfield()
      ....
      ....
```

this is my trace error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 226, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 109, in inner_run
    autoreload.raise_last_exception()
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 249, in raise_last_exception
    six.reraise(*_exception)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 226, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 18, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 108, in populate
    app_config.import_models(all_models)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 202, in import_models
    self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/root/inventarios/provider/models.py", line 5, in <module>
    from products.models import Product
  File "/root/inventarios/products/models.py", line 4, in <module>
    from provider.models import Provider
```

i dont understand why get this error, this get only when try  to runserver, please any suggest. thanks !!

Comment: is there an \__init\__.py in your provider directory?

Comment: yes all apps get the empty __init__.py

Comment: Does provider also import product?

Comment: yeah but other class in the same model. i'm going to edit my question for add this code

Comment: Run `python manage.py runserver --traceback --verbosity 2` see what error it gives you.

Comment: thanks i paste my traceback.. @FranndyAbreu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks to all for your answers, but my error is:

> circular import error
>   i solve my problem change this:

```
 class Catalogue(models.Model):
      product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
      provider = models.ForeignKey(Provider, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

by this:

```
 class Catalogue(models.Model):
      product = models.ForeignKey('products.Product', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
      provider = models.ForeignKey(Provider, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

but do not finish understanding why i'm get this error if the import is correct ..
why is circular import  error?..thanks..!!

Answer (score 0):

If you created a file named provider and put your models.py file inside of it, you should create a `__init__.py` file so it can be recognized as a module making it possible to be imported.

Have you tried that? Your `__init__.py`can be a blank file

Comment: yeah thanks i create the app provider with the command django...python manage.py startapp provider..this create this file(__init__.py)..

Comment: Yes, but if you created a folder for Provider and a folder for Product, and inside each one of them you have your models.py file. If I'm not mistaken you're gonna need a ````__init.py```` file inside each one of these folders. Besides the one you already have that was created in your startapp command. Creating this file inside the folders you're saying that their content are modules that can be imported